# Wifi is not working on a new computer Lenovo IdeaPad S145

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I bought a new computer Lenovo IdeaPad S145 and made a fresh installation on Ubuntu 20.04 there. The problem is that wifi card was not detected.

I tried to install different drivers but with no success. Mainly because I can't reveal what is exact version my wifi card. The output of `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A3` is just:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c82f]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c02f]
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: KIOXIA Corporation Device [1e0f:0001]
        Subsystem: KIOXIA Corporation Device [1e0f:0001]
```

So, I see that the card is Realtek but the exact version seems to be missing.

What I've tried so far:

- Did a system update to ensure that the kernel is of latest version
- Checked if there are soft or hard locks with `rfkill` - there are not
- Tried to install 3rd party drivers, I installed rtl8821ce and rtl8192cu
- Tried to disable airplane mode
- Checked if there are additional drivers in **Software & Updates** - there are not

As advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/425155), I attach the [wireless script output in a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KVghBCcP) with more info.
Please note that currently I'm connected with usb netstick, which might affect the results of the script.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update:**

The problem was solved after installing this driver: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Comment: The output of `lspci -v` is not particularly interesting. Post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A3`.

Comment: Please see my answer here >>> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248469/no-wifi-adapter-found-lenovo-ideapad-s145-20-04-ubuntu/1248548#1248548

Comment: Looks like a very new device, 8822ce. Here is a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1886247. I doubt 8821ce or 8192cu have any relevance here.

Comment: @Raffles The secure boot is off, this info is also shown in attached pastebin. And in command line I get notification that rtl8821ce-dkms is of the latest version already.

Comment: @mikewhatever wow, this is exaclty my case, thanks a lot. I will follow that bug report. I tried 8821ce and 8192cu because I saw many people with similar problem who told this helped them.

Comment: @mikewhatever In bug report that you linked I found a git repo with needed driver: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 , after I installed that driver wifi get working. Thanks again.

Comment: Per above bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1886247) - the fix has been released for this bug, so with fresh kernel this should work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the kernel using in 20.04 with the driver you are needing so i suggest you to try to update your kernel, here is a tutorial

*If you already have the needed kernel just jump to the fourth step*

First you must uninstall all privative drivers you have(Nvidia,ATI(AMD)) mostly your video drivers this is just to prevent future troubles and reinstall them after you updated your kernel

Check this [link](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7/amd64/) to download the needed files

First Step) Now Download the files named:

1. File: "linux-headers-5.7.0-050700_5.7.0-050700.202006082127_all.deb"
2. File: "linux-image-unsigned-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202006082127_amd64.deb"
3. File: "linux-modules-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202006082127_amd64.deb"

Second Step)

It's time to install all the debs(Gui Method)

just double click the downloaded packages and install them via software center

It's time to install all the .deb packages(terminal method)

"sudo" -Ask for admin privileges
"dpkg -i" -Used to install Debian Packages

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-5.7.0-050700_5.7.0-050700.202006082127_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-unsigned-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202006082127_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-modules-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202006082127_amd64.deb
```

Third Step)Once all packages are installed

This updates your grub to the latest kernel you have installed

Is time to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your Laptop and now ubuntu will boot with the new kernel

Fourth Step)
install this packages to compile the third party driver

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Then clone this git

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git -b rtw88
```

Now you can install it

navigate to the git clone directory look for the file named "rtw8822ce.c" and search for the string "0xC822" and change it to "0xC82F" save and close the file

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Almost Last Step)

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot

Last Step)

enjoy your wifi card!

NOTE

if something fails remember to search the packages you installed and uninstall them

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=68&t=296139
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=320112

Comment: In the bug report that mikewhatever linked in the comments to question, I found a link to git repo that contained drivers for wifi card https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 , after installing it - everything worked.

Comment: that's great! was the same driver anyway, i'm glad that you have it working now

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with "Software & Updates" tools in ubuntu 20?. Just give a try...

Go to software and updates.
Go to Additional Drivers.

You will see the list of additional device are attached with your system. Choose the wifi drivers and install it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Sorry forgot to state in the question. There are no available additional drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You should always be careful to install third party drivers on your system, however, the driver you stated worked for this laptop. https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

My 'lspci -nnk | grep Net -A3' output is

lspci -nnk | grep Net -A3 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c82f] Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c02f]

This proves that I have the same configuration as you from factory default, and that my answer is highly specific and relevant to this particular problem. In this case Ubuntu does not provide any additional suggested drivers so the choice to pick which of all the drivers out there should be narrowed down to a Realtek driver based on the output of the command listed above.

I would only install drivers if I had the certainty that it would not bring any risk to my system. In this case knowing that this driver works for a particular make and model of the laptop is key information, given that the support from the vendor of the hardware, is minimal, if any. Debugging lack of such driver support is not a trivial matter.

The laptop is the Lenovo IdeaPad S145. Since this laptop is fairly new, if this is a repeated problem, it is currently difficult to find any other information on this topic as I have already tried.